# An anti debug method on Linux

Tags: gdb, anti-debugging

I have found this question [(linux) How to debug a "debugger"?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6467/linux-how-to-debug-a-debugger)
It is an anti debug technique, the parent creates a forked process and ptrace it. Now gdb can not attach top the child process.
I would like to know how efficient this technique is: is there a way to bypass this method and to attach a debugger to the child? (for example - if possible - by detaching it first) I met this method reading about Apriorit, but they also use nanomites.

EDIT: There are some advices at [(linux) How to debug a "debugger"?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6467/linux-how-to-debug-a-debugger) but I would like to see some real examples.

EDIT2: If somebody can show how easy or hard is to bypass it that would also show how effective is it.

Comment: _"is there a way to bypass this method and to attach a debugger to the child?"_ - The answer to your question is [the answer to the question to which you linked](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/6494/1562).

Comment: @peterferrie, if that post contains a detailed answer with example, than yes.

Comment: @JasonGeffner, can you show me how?